# Vue / Lodash filter Array by another array's values

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm continuing my JavaScript learning and I've come across something that isn't clear to me to work around.

In my Vue data object I have:

```
  data: {
    allergenFilter: [],
    categoryFilter: [],
    results: {},
  },
```

I have an array of checkboxes which allows me to select allergens for products, it populates my `allergenFilter` Vue property like this:

```
[
  0: "nut-free",
  1: "milk-free"
]
```

But I also have a list of allergens that a product has/doesn't have that I'd like to match the products that include the choices. This is an example from a product:

```
[
  0:"vegetarian"
  1:"vegan"
  2:"egg-free"
  3:"nut-free"
]
```

I've tried to filter the results by doing this:

```
  this.results.filter(result =>
    result.allergens.includes(
      this.allergenFilter
    )
  )
```

But it doesn't work because of the key:value pairings, so I know the issue, but I'm not entirely sure of how to see if an arrays values are included in another array's values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another nested loop - check if `.some` of the allergens are included in the `allergenFilter`.

```
this.results.filter(result =>
    result.allergens.some(
        allergen => this.allergenFilter.includes(allergen)
    )
)
```

If you need *all* of the `allergenFilter` to be included, then use `.every`.

```
this.results.filter(result =>
    this.allergenFilter.every(
        allergen => result.allergens.includes(allergen)
    )
);
```

Comment: `.every` works really well, thank you so much. Though I do seem to get a `some() is not a function` error when I use your first answer

Comment: Is `result.allergens` an array? If so, it should work. Your code has `[ 0: "nut-free", 1: "milk-free" ]` which is invalid syntax but looks kind of like an array. Array literals don't have key-value pairs, only values, and [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) exists.

Comment: It is yeah, key value pairs. If I copy your second answer and change `every` to `some` it works so not sure if there is a genuine syntax error in the first one?

Comment: `.every` is the answer I needed for sure, but just an FYI on the `.some` answer

Comment: Yes, your code of `[ 0: "nut-free", 1: "milk-free" ]` is definitely a syntax error, just try it: `const someArr = [ 0: "nut-free", 1: "milk-free" ]` will throw

Comment: Yeah I understand, but just copied what's output - https://i.ibb.co/XpQWjW6/Screenshot-2021-09-04-at-15-24-32.png